# O level additional mathematics (applied), obtaining solutions in the correct order

Tags: classical-mechanics

This is a question from an old O level additional mathematics book by T A Humphreys (1967). It is given as follows:

Strings of length 4 ft and 3 ft are attached to a fixed point O and to the ends A, B respectively of a rod 5 ft long and weighing 15 lb. wt. The rod rests in equilibrium in a horizontal position supported by a smooth peg at C. If AC = 1 ft find the tensions in the strings and the reaction at the peg.

Solutions are:

$T_A$=$6$$\frac{3}{22}$$lb. wt.$
$T_B$=$8$$\frac{2}{11}$$lb. wt.$
$R$=$4$$\frac{17}{22}$$lb. wt$

I have, after considerable effort, managed to obtain the answers given. However, I am unable to obtain them in the order given in the question and I was wondering if this was normal.

My solution involved finding R first by taking moments about O, therefore eliminating $T_A$ and $T_B$. It was only at this point that I could solve the two equations I had formed for $T_A$ and $T_B$. I should add that this chapters is devoted to moments of forces so I would imagine this is the way to solve - there may be other more novel solutions but I'm not sure.

Apologies if I'm either being pedantic here or have asked a question with an obvious answer. I would just like to know if I'm missing something.

Many thanks in advance for any advice given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show how to obtain $R$, considering in competent units

$$
\cases{
OA=4\\
OB=3\\
AB=5\\
AC=1\\
w = 15
}
$$

Solving for $AX,XB,OX$

$$
\cases{
AX+XB=AB\\
\frac{XB}{OX} =\frac{OB}{OA}\\
AX\cdot XB = OX^2
}
$$

where $X$ is the vertical projection of $O$ onto $AB$ we have

$$
\cases{
AX = \frac{AB\cdot OA^2}{OA^2+OB^2}\\
XB = \frac{AB\cdot OB^2}{OA^2+OB^2}\\
OX = \frac{AB\cdot OA\cdot OB}{OA^2+OB^2}\\
}
$$

now computing the momenta equilibrium regarding $O$ we have

$$
\left(\frac 12 AB-XB\right)w - (AB-AC-XB)R=0
$$

and solving for $R$ we obtain

$$
R = \frac 12\frac{AB(OA^2-OB^2)}{AB\cdot OA^2-AC(OA^2+OB^2)}w = \frac{105}{22}=4\frac{17}{22}
$$

To find $T_A, T_B$ we need to solve

$$
T_A \vec{OA}+T_B\vec{OB}+(R+w)\vec{e}_y = 0
$$

where

$$
\cases{
\vec{OA} = \frac{1}{OA}\left(AX,OX\right)\\
\vec{OB} = \frac{1}{OB}\left(-XB,OX\right)\\
\vec e_y = (0,-1)
}
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.